# How does Terraform know what files to load?

Tags: terraform

How do commands such as `terraform plan` know / decide **which files to use**?

`-help` shows a `DIR-OR-PLAN` argument, but doesn't show how to use it:

```
$ terraform -help plan
Usage: terraform plan [options] [DIR-OR-PLAN]
```

How do I specify **what files to use**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `[DIR-OR-PLAN]` is omitted (e.g. `terraform plan`) then it defaults to **the current directory**.

Terraform **loads all configuration files** (i.e. files ending in `.tf` or `.tf.json`) within that directory in alphabetical order.

So in answer to:

> How do I specify **what files to use**?

You must ensure only the files you wish `terraform` to use are in the directory.

See [**Load Order and Semantics**](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/load.html) for more info.

Comment: In addition, terraform creates a dependency graph from all the resources and orders them according to dependency, running many of them in parallel.